# My apache2 VirtualHost keep showing "It's working" instead of my site

Tags: apache, webserver, apache2

I'm doing a project for school where I have to host 2 pages on a web server. I chose to do a VirtualHost using Apache2 but when it keeps showing me a "It works" page. The page is located [here](http://www.wt5.ephec-ti.be/).

We are using a DNS server but the probleme seems to not be coming from this one.

Here is one of the *.conf* file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jongen.philemon@wt5.ephec-ti.be
    ServerName wt5.ephec-ti.be
    ServerAlias www.wt5.ephec-ti.be

    DocumentRoot /var/www/monsite
    <Directory /><br>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/monsite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also changed the *apache2.conf* like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jongen.philemon@wt5.ephec-ti.be
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site

    <Directory /var/www/site/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You can also check our [wiki](https://github.com/p-jongen/AdminProjetG5/wiki/Infrastructure-WEB) on the GitHub to see all the steps I followed.

Thank's

Comment: 1) that <br> must be for the content here right?  If it is on the real file, remove it.  2) in your second VirtualHost, there is no ServerName.  VirtualHost is used to differentiate between 2 different domains, in the same Apache HTTPD.  3) VirtualHosts should contain all the directives for each site.  Ex. ErrorLog in both VH.  4) if all your directories are linked to the same domain, there should be only one VH, with all directories in that single VH.

Answer (score 0):

I got to fix it by re-doing it using a Dockerfile. I uptated the files and the wiki on my github if you have the same issue !